# I cannot read certain text cells in Excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an Excel file with some text, data and stocks on it. I am using openpyxl and random to pick a random stock and then write its data in another document, however for some reason when I run my code I get error "#value!". Originally I thought it was because openpyxl cannot read text as I have never used openyxl and I'm just learning through https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/. But if I try and read a cell that has something like "symbol" or "hello" in it, it works perfectly fine, for some reason the stocks just don't print even though they appear to be texts if you look at the top inspect bar. Is there a simple solution for this or do I need to change something in my Excel document?

```
import random
from datetime import date
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook

today = date.today()
dateToday = today.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
randomNumber = random.randint(2,749)
print(randomNumber)
print(dateToday)
randomCell = 'A' + str(randomNumber)
print('randomCell is:')
print(randomCell)

InfoWB = load_workbook(filename= 'ExcelSheet.xlsx')
InfoWS = InfoWB.active
randomStock = InfoWS[randomCell].value
print(randomStock)

dbWB = load_workbook(filename= 'StockPicks.xlsx')
db = dbWB.active
# This next bit doesn't work either but I haven't researched or tried fixing it yet
# dbWB['A2'] = randomStock 
dbWB.save('StockPicks.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue, turns out because I was using the stocks name to generate stock data using an Excel feature all the stocks were not considered text even though it looked like text.